# Find $A(v_1+v_2)$ and $A(3v_1)$ given eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If $v_1=[-1;5]$ and $v_2=[-3;5]$ are eigenvectors of a matrix $A$
>
> corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-1$ and $\lambda_2=1$, find $A(v_1+v_2)$ and $A(3v_1).$

I managed to find $A,$ which I believe is $[[2,\frac 35];[-5,-2]]$, but I'm unsure of how to continue.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  By linearity, $A(v_1+v_2)=A(v_1)+A(v_2)$

Comment: How do you get two As? I only get one A.

Comment: My equation with two As holds because $A$ is a [linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map)

Comment: You don’t need to construct $A$ explicitly to solve this. Use the definition of an eigenvector and linearity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You could say $v_1+v_2=[-1;5]+[-3;5]=[-4;10]$,
>
> and when you multiply that by the matrix you found, the result is $[-2;0].$
>
> Alternatively, by linearity, $A(v_1+v_2)=A(v_1)+A(v_2)=-1v_1+1v_2=[-2;0].$

To find $A(3v_1)$, you could say $3v_1=[-3;15],$

and when you multiply that by the matrix you found, the result is $[3;-15],$

but I find it again easier to use linearity:  $A(3v_1)=3A(v_1)=-3(v_1)=[3;-15].$